# Grafana renders data incorrectly for the last minute

Tags: graphite, grafana

I work as a NOC operator and monitor performance of an Amazon Cloud Application. Ops team uses Graphite to monitor its health and Grafana on top of it to render fancy graphs. By design "graphite" collects data every minute
But I've encountered an issue with Grafana, it renders incorrect data (or not fully collected, see a screenshot below) for the last minute. 
Can I fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xXCK.png

Comment: Are those graphs based on accumulations of multiple metrics or other formulas? Maybe only some of the involved metrics are up2date so you get values below expectation... Or it's a caching thing - Graphite caches heavily in memory but in theory should manage to deliver up2date metrics at any time...

Comment: yes, these graphs aggregate data from many VMs (thousands), so most likely you are right.
Is there a way to exclude the data from last minute?

Comment: To work around you might use `timeShift(your.metric,"1min")` to go back in time on your.metric.

Comment: @cmur2, I've just read about that function in docs and was inattentive, sorry about that.


It seems like it doesn't work with GroupByNode, this doesn't work:
`timeShift(groupByNode(agg.*.*.*.*.somedata.*.*.count,2,'sumSeries'),"2min")`

Comment: Are you using statsd? If so, you are probably configuring the retention rates wrongly, see https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/graphite.md

Comment: @dukebody, thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are doing a sumSeries() (or similar) on multiple series which arrive from different sources. When the sources have not all delivered the data yet, the sum for the last data point will be too low, because the some data is missing.

To cosmetically fix it and provide a projection of the near future, you can use the [`keepLastValue`](https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.keepLastValue) function. It re-uses the previous value for up to `limit` missing data points when calculating the query. This is of course inaccurate, but as it is not persistent, the inaccuracy will be replaced with actual data as soon as it arrives.

Use it with a low limit and make sure to monitor the overall latency of the graphite setup to notice when something goes wrong (otherwise, keepLastValue can easily hide issues with the monitoring).